# Jasmine testing runs code in illogical order when iterating over mutliple results in a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to write a test to grab the contents of a div and compare them with my expectation.

I know I can expect multiple results, so I've been trying to iterate over the results one at a time and concatenate them into one string which I can then compare against my expectation.

Code snippets below don't seem to work as expected. My console returns `"result to be returned: "` with no results before it returns `"result INSIDE while:  1"` and `"result INSIDE while:  1  2"`.

This doesn't make any sense to me... Hopefully i've explained well enough what i'm trying to do. The code isn't great at the moment because i've been chopping and changing bits to test what is happening.

A 'tl;dr' summary of what i'm hoping someone can help with :)

- How can I iterate over each item returned by the `element.all` line and concatenate the values into a string for the function to return to my test?
- Can anyone help me understand why the if/else appears to be true when i has been set to 0 beforehand (I'm sure that `items.length` is 2 in this case)
- Can anyone point me to a good place to read up on promises? I have a feeling my poor understanding of promises is holding me back...

**Test:**

```
var resultPage = require('../page/result.page.js');
var ExpectedArticle1Details = browser.params.articleInTransitInTransit[0];
var ExpectedArticle2Details = browser.params.articleNotCompliantPossibleDelay[0];
var ExpectedIDs = ' ' + ExpectedArticle1Details.TrackingID + '  ' + ExpectedArticle2Details.TrackingID

expect(resultPage.allTrackingIDsAreVisible()).toEqual(ExpectedIDs);
```

**resultPage:**

```
this.allTrackingIDsAreVisible = function () {
    var result = "";
    element.all(by.css(trackingIDs)).then(function (items) { var i = 0;
      while (i <= items.length) {
        if (i === items.length) {
          console.log("result to be returned: " + result);
          return result;
        }
        else
        {
          items[i].getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function (value){result += value; console.log("result INSIDE while: " + result)})
        }
        i = i + 1;
      }
    })  
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain why that happens first, then suggest a solution.
you call a while loop, which always does something async (a promise), so it always adds it to the queue, and then goes and does the next line synchronously, that would be i+=1;, so the loop ends before all the promises could resolve, `result` didn't even change yet, and it already returned empty.

What you should use, is a recursive function on element.all(by.css(trackingIDs)), whith the signature:

```
addToResult(elementArray, i, result) {};
```

and each time you do:

```
items[i].getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function (value){
    addToResult(elementArray, i + 1, result += value)
})
```

dont forget to stop the recursion when `i === elementArray.length`, and then return result

Comment: Hi @vrachlin, Thanks for your suggestion. I'm struggling with it at the moment but it's the end of my work day so my brain might have just switched off already.

If you're able to clarify: In your suggestion, where would the `addToResult` function live? Does `elementArray === items` from my resultPage code?

I'll look into implementing your suggestion in the morning and let you know how I go. :)

Comment: @ShaneNayler elementArray is indeed items from your code, so the first call would be `var result = addToResult(items, 0, "")`, the addToResult will be in the same scope as where it will be used, in this case or inside `this.allTrackingIDsAreVisible`, or in the same scope as it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to solve this problem is by using protractor's inbuilt `.each()` function, rather than looping through the elements using for or while loops. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.css(trackingIDs)).each(function (eachItem){
    eachItem.getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function (value){
        addToResult(elementArray, i + 1, result += value);
    });
});
```

Now there are chances that the above data isn't synchronised and may vary in the order which usually occurs because of the protractor's async nature. In such case, use `.map()` function to retrieves the data in synchronised form. Here's an example -

```
element.all(by.css(trackingIDs)).map(function (items){
    return items.getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function (value){
        return value;
    });
}).then(function(val){
    addToResult(elementArray, i + 1, result += val);
});
```

- [more details about each function](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each)
- [more details about map function](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)

Hope it helps.